# SUMO Simulation. Detecting high Traffic and reducing the speed limit

Tags: python, simulation, network-traffic, sumo

I am learning SUMO from beggining, I read and learned most of tutorials from: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials . What I want to do now is to make Cars slow down when there is a Traffic on a Road. I only know how to change the speed limit after a certain Time from here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Variable_Speed_Signs . Do you know how can I change the speed limit when there is Traffic? I think that changing the value of speed Signs is the best Idea here, but I don't how do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as event triggered speed signs in SUMO, so you probably need to do that via [TraCI](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI). The easiest way is probably to start with the [TraCI tutorial for trafficlights](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials/TraCI4Traffic_Lights) and then use functions like [traci.edge.getLastStepOccupancy](http://sumo.dlr.de/daily/pydoc/traci._edge.html#EdgeDomain-getLastStepOccupancy) to find out whether vehicles are on the edge in question and then traci.edge.setMaxSpeed to set a new speed.